# Packaging Servlets (symbol error on compile)

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, compiler-errors, packaging

I've been building my first (somewhat large) tomcat/mysql project. 
Things have been going well, but now that I want to place my servlets into packages (and import classes) things don't want to compile.

Servlet Repository: C:\tomcat\webapps\web\web-inf\classes\com\coreservlets

Package name: com.coreservlets

cmd shell command(compile): (I know this classpath / compile path works)

```
C:\tomcat\webapps\web\web-inf\classes\com\coreservlets>

javac -classpath c:\apache\tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar LoginHandler.java
```

I have two servlets in the repository (one compiles, the other doesn't). The one that doesn't compile gets this message when compiling

```
  LoginHandler.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
  import com.coreservlets.MyUser;
                         ^
  symbol:   class MyUser
  location: package com.coreservlets
```

my XML:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginHandler</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.coreservlets.LoginHandler</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyUser</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.coreservlets.MyUser</servlet-class>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginHandler</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginHandler</url-pattern>
</serlvet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyUser</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyUser</url-pattern>
</serlvet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

The LoginHandler code snippit

```
package com.coreservlets;
import com.coreservlets.MyUser;
```

The MyUser code snippit

```
package com.coreservlets;
```

---

The MyUser.java file will compile without and trouble. 
Only the LoginHandler fails to compile. I see that it understands where the class MyUser is, and sees the package location... what am I doing wrong here?

*This is what I am trying to do more or less (just get servlets packaged and be able to import/export java classes/constructors: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-packaging.htm

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem with classpath. There are many ways to solve it, the simplest is call

```
javac -classpath c:\apache\tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar *.java
```

BTW, more precise, but also very simple tutorial is http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-servlet-example-write-deploy-run/

Comment: No, can't be class path... and that is the call I make...  as shown above. Other servlets compile just fine using that shell command. Only this one gives me that problem. I have no problem compiling servlets, only servlets which use import statements.

Comment: Perhaps this is a better tutorial showing what I am trying to accomplish : http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/11/mvc-architecture-with-servlets-and-jsp/

Comment: Must be classpath. If you compile LoginHandler.java, compiler needs access to com.coreservlets.MyUser. There is no such class on classpath, because classpath is only servlet-api. Finally, compilation fails. Other your servlets pass compilation, because compiler needs only servler-api - and has it.

Comment: Then what does it need to be changed to?? I don't understand what you are saying. The commands he typed and the command I used are the same.

Comment: I am inside the directory where com.coreservlets.MyUser when I make the javac call...  Ex. c:\tomcat\webapps\web\web-inf\classes\com\endure> javac -classpath c:\apache\tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar LoginHandler.java

Comment: 1. I already wrote my command, with *.java at the end. It works on my computer.
2. You are inside com/coreservlets folder. Classpath is servlet-api.jar. You want compile LoginHandler.java. Compiler needs access to com.coreservlets.MyUser. Is that class visible on classpath? No. Is compilation possible? No
When you are within com/coreservlets it means compiler has accessible source file LoginHandler.java. But MyUser.class is not accessible because classpath points somewhere else.
Classpath <> current folder

Comment: AHH! I see now! * denotes that you compile everything in that folder all at once! Yes I see now, thank you very much!